# Cron job cannot open input file

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to create cron job on Mac. I set a script to execute every 1 minute. Every minute I get mail with:

> "Could not open input file: /Users/andrejolesov/Documents/script.php".

String for `cronjob -e` is:

```
"* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q Users/andrejolesov/Documents/script.php"
```

I also tried:

```
"* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /Users/andrejolesov/Documents/script.php"
```

P.S: script.php has 777 permissions. If I run the script in terminal it works.